# Is there an alternative for zip(*iterable) when the iterable consists of millions of elements?

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, iterable-unpacking

I have come across a code like this:

```
from random import randint

class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

points = [Point(randint(1, 10), randint(1, 10)) for _ in range(10)]
xs = [point.x for point in points]
ys = [point.y for point in points]
```

And I think this code is *not* Pythonic because it repeats itself. If another dimension is added to `Point` class, a whole new loop needs to be written like:

```
zs = [point.z for point in points]
```

So I tried to make it more Pythonic by writing something like this:

```
xs, ys = zip(*[(point.x, point.y) for point in p])
```

If a new dimension is added, no problem:

```
xs, ys, zs = zip(*[(point.x, point.y, point.z) for point in p])
```

But this is almost 10 times **slower** than the other solution when there are millions of points, although it has only one loop. I think it is because `*` operator needs to unpack millions of arguments to the `zip` function which is horrible. So my question is:

*Is there a way to change the code above so that it is **as fast as before** and **Pythonic** (without using 3rd party libraries)?*

Comment: For one, you could use a generator instead of constructing a complete list: `zip(*((point.x, point.y, point.z) for point in p))`. How much that will help as opposed to using another approach entirely I can't say off the top of my head.

Comment: @deceze I don't know why but it is even more slower.

Comment: @deceze: That won't help at all. Argument unpacking always converts it to a `tuple` from whatever it happened to be, so that just uses a more expensive generator expression to populate the `tuple`, rather than a cheaper listcomp followed by quick shallow copy.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I see, that explains it, thanks.

Comment: maybe storing points data in a "high-performance" data structure like pandas dataframe could help to make it fast. but it supposes to use pandas...

Comment: @Tryph Of course it will be faster but I think that would be cheating :) I could write this code in C and it will be 5 times faster. I'm trying to understand why it is slow and how could I improve it.

Comment: For any practical problem involving a large number of points in arbitrary dimensions, the best option is to use the array structure provided by Numpy instead of using a list of objects. Unless using Numpy (or Pandas...) is forbidden for some reason.

Comment: @aerobiomat Please check the edit I made.

Answer (score 8):

I just tested several ways of zipping `Point` coordinates and looked for their performance with increasing number of points.

Below are the functions I used to test:

```py
def hardcode(points):
    # a hand crafted comprehension for each coordinate
    return [point.x for point in points], [point.y for point in points]


def using_zip(points):
    # using the "problematic" qip function
    return zip(*((point.x, point.y) for point in points))


def loop_and_comprehension(points):
    # making comprehension from a list of coordinate names
    zipped = []
    for coordinate in ('x', 'y'):
        zipped.append([getattr(point, coordinate) for point in points])
    return zipped


def nested_comprehension(points):
    # making comprehension from a list of coordinate names using nested
    # comprehensions
    return [
        [getattr(point, coordinate) for point in points]
        for coordinate in ('x', 'y')
    ]
```

Using timeit I timed execution of each function with different number of points and here are the results:

```
comparing processing times using 10 points and 10000000 iterations
hardcode................. 14.12024447 [+0%]
using_zip................ 16.84289724 [+19%]
loop_and_comprehension... 30.83631476 [+118%]
nested_comprehension..... 30.45758349 [+116%]

comparing processing times using 100 points and 1000000 iterations
hardcode................. 9.30594717 [+0%]
using_zip................ 13.74953714 [+48%]
loop_and_comprehension... 19.46766583 [+109%]
nested_comprehension..... 19.27818860 [+107%]

comparing processing times using 1000 points and 100000 iterations
hardcode................. 7.90372457 [+0%]
using_zip................ 12.51523594 [+58%]
loop_and_comprehension... 18.25679913 [+131%]
nested_comprehension..... 18.64352790 [+136%]

comparing processing times using 10000 points and 10000 iterations
hardcode................. 8.27348382 [+0%]
using_zip................ 18.23079485 [+120%]
loop_and_comprehension... 18.00183383 [+118%]
nested_comprehension..... 17.96230063 [+117%]

comparing processing times using 100000 points and 1000 iterations
hardcode................. 9.15848662 [+0%]
using_zip................ 22.70730675 [+148%]
loop_and_comprehension... 17.81126971 [+94%]
nested_comprehension..... 17.86892597 [+95%]

comparing processing times using 1000000 points and 100 iterations
hardcode................. 9.75002857 [+0%]
using_zip................ 23.13891725 [+137%]
loop_and_comprehension... 18.08724660 [+86%]
nested_comprehension..... 18.01269820 [+85%]

comparing processing times using 10000000 points and 10 iterations
hardcode................. 9.96045920 [+0%]
using_zip................ 23.11653558 [+132%]
loop_and_comprehension... 17.98296033 [+81%]
nested_comprehension..... 18.17317708 [+82%]

comparing processing times using 100000000 points and 1 iterations
hardcode................. 64.58698246 [+0%]
using_zip................ 92.53437881 [+43%]
loop_and_comprehension... 73.62493845 [+14%]
nested_comprehension..... 62.99444739 [-2%]
```

---

We can see that the gap between the "harcoded" solution and the solutions with comprehensions built with `gettattr` seems to constantly reduce as the number of points grows.

So, for a very big number of points it could be a good idea to use generated comprehensions from a list of coordinates:

```
[[getattr(point, coordinate) for point in points]
 for coordinate in ('x', 'y')]
```

However, for a small number of points this is the worst solution (from the ones I tested at least).

---

For information, here is the code I used to run this benchmark:

```py
import timeit


...


def compare(nb_points, nb_iterations):
    reference = None
    points = [Point(randint(1, 100), randint(1, 100))
              for _ in range(nb_points)]
    print("comparing processing times using {} points and {} iterations"
          .format(nb_points, nb_iterations))

    for func in (hardcode, using_zip, loop_and_comprehension, nested_comprehension):
        duration = timeit.timeit(lambda: func(points), number=nb_iterations)

        print('{:.<25} {:0=2.8f} [{:0>+.0%}]'
              .format(func.__name__, duration,
                      0 if reference is None else (duration / reference - 1)))

        if reference is None:
            reference = duration

    print("-" * 80)



compare(10, 10000000)
compare(100, 1000000)
compare(1000, 100000)
compare(10000, 10000)
compare(100000, 1000)
compare(1000000, 100)
compare(10000000, 10)
compare(100000000, 1)
```

Answer (score 8):

The problem with `zip(*iter)` is that it will iterate over the entire iterable and pass the resulting sequence in as args to zip.

So these are functionally the same:

**Using *:** `xs, ys = zip(*[(p.x, p.y) for p in ((0,1),(0,2),(0,3))])`

**Using positionals:** `xz, ys = zip((0,1),(0,2),(0,3))`.

Obviously, if there are millions of positional arguments this will be slow.

The iterator approach is the only work around.

I did a web search for `python itertools unzip`. Sadly the closest `itertools` gets is `tee`. In the link to the gist above, a tuple of iterators from `itertools.tee` is returned from this implementation of `iunzip`: https://gist.github.com/andrix/106334.

**I had to convert it to python3:**

```
from random import randint
import itertools
import time
from operator import itemgetter

def iunzip(iterable):
    """Iunzip is the same as zip(*iter) but returns iterators, instead of 
    expand the iterator. Mostly used for large sequence"""

    _tmp, iterable = itertools.tee(iterable, 2)
    iters = itertools.tee(iterable, len(next(_tmp)))
    return (map(itemgetter(i), it) for i, it in enumerate(iters))

class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

points = [Point(randint(1, 10), randint(1, 10)) for _ in range(1000000)]
itime = time.time()
xs = [point.x for point in points]
ys = [point.y for point in points]
otime = time.time() - itime
itime += otime
print(f"original: {otime}")
xs, ys = zip(*[(p.x, p.y) for p in points])
otime = time.time() - itime
itime += otime
print(f"unpacking into zip: {otime}")
xs, ys = iunzip(((p.x, p.y) for p in points))
for _ in zip(xs, ys): pass
otime = time.time() - itime
itime += otime
print(f"iunzip: {otime}")
```

**Output:**

```
original: 0.1282501220703125
unpacking into zip: 1.286362886428833
iunzip: 0.3046858310699463
```

So the iterator is definitely better than unpacking into positional args. Not to mention the fact my 4GB of memory got eaten up when I went to 10 million points... However, I'm not convinced the `iunzip` iterator above is as optimal as it could be if it was a python builtin given that iterating twice to do the unzip as in the "original" method is still by far the fastest (~4x faster trying with various length of points).

Seems like `iunzip` should be a thing. I'm surprised it's not a python builtin or part of itertools...